# Can't expire page due to custom routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm caching this page: `match "/review_(:game_id)" => "reviews#show"`

My controller looks like:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  caches_page :show

  def show
    expires_in 1.week, :public => true
  end
end
```

I'm trying to have a rake task to clear up the file cache for that specific page every week, but expire_page doesn't seem to work for this one, Maybe it expects a full path? but i can't provide that because there are hundreds of games.

```
task :expire_game_reviews => :environment do
  ApplicationController.expire_page "/reviews/show"
  puts "Cache cleared"
end
```

Any ideas? or maybe even better a work around to specify a timeout parameter in `caches_page`?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, expire_page won't cut it in this setup.

The solution is to do it manually. Since there is nothing else that is going to clear this cache, you need to remove the files yourself. That is easy:

```
task :expire_game_reviews => :environment do
  cpath = ActionController::Base.page_cache_directory

  unless cpath == Rails.root + "/public"
    FileUtils.rm_r(Dir.glob(cpath + "/*")) rescue Errno::ENOENT
  end

  Rails.cache.clear
end
```

After removing those files in the /public directory (or wherever else you put them - you can use regex to match the directory and files with FileUtils), you need to clear the Rails cache in /tmp directory so that it doesn't pull the cache from there after controller gives an order.

Comment: Yeah. My assumption was that this is the only route you're page caching so it might be a compromise you could make since this is once a week.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried expiring pages explicitly specifying the id of the resource?

Something like :

```
task :expire_game_reviews => :environment do
  Game.all.each do |game|
    ApplicationController.expire_page "/review_#{game.id}"
    puts "Cache cleared for review #{game.id}"
  end
end
```

In my opinion, asking Rails to expire cache "/reviews/show" can't work because the key associated to your cache is something like "review_123", but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with an explicit path for each review? expire_page requires the full path you stored the cache under (but not params):

```
expire_page(:controller => "reviews", :action => "show", :id => r.id)
```

If that doesn't work, you can find out what keys you are actually storing in the file cache with something like this:

```
find ./tmp/cache -type f | xargs ruby -e 'require "cgi";puts CGI::unescape(ARGV.sort.join("\n")).gsub(/.*tmp\/cache\/\w*\/\w*\//,"")'
```

NB that's only to explore what keys you are storing and debug. Then, when you know the key pattern you want to match, you could try expiring it with a sweeper in the file system which clears the entire page cache (not all caches, just page caches). Unfortunately expire_page doesn't take a regexp like expire_fragment.